# jQuery legacy call affecting new jQuery datepicker call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In a test page I am able to use datepicker to produce an clickable calendar which takes the user to another page and passes the date selected for a DB search. However, when I put it in the shell of the page it is to be used in, an old call used to display an online video in a side bar, interferes with the calendar. I looked up the issue and added the following:

load different versions of jQuery:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       console.log($().jquery); // This prints v1.4.2
       console.log($j().jquery); // This prints v1.10.4
      });
   </script>
 </script>

 <script> 

$j(function() {
    var pickerOpts ={
       dayNamesShort: true
    };

    $j( "#eventscalendar" ).datepicker({
          dayNamesShort: true,
          firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
          altField: "#calendarForm",
          altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $j(this).change();
          }
    });
});

   $j(this).change(function() {
   //alert("index.php?date=" + calendarForm.value);
   window.location.href = "listings_NEW.php?event_date=" + calendarForm.value +  '&x=' + Math.random();
  });
  </script>
```

However, the onclick function no longer works. I an using a hidden submit in the datepicker.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try `noConflict` right after the first one.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You said `However, the onclick function no longer works` but there is no `onclick` function in your code.

You defined this `$j(this).change(function() {` seems you aimed datepicker but it doesn't work that way.

Try this one

```
$j(function() {
    var pickerOpts ={
       dayNamesShort: true
    };

    $j( "#eventscalendar" ).datepicker({
          dayNamesShort: true,
          firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
          altField: "#calendarForm",
          altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          onSelect: function(dateText) {
               window.location.href = "listings_NEW.php?event_date=" + dateText +  '&x=' + Math.random();
          }
    });
});
```